# How to use a var in ajax url with action razor syntax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a function that calls a method in controller through an Action URL, but I need use a parameter like name of Method, but this is not possible in this way.

```
function changeDropDownList(id, dropNameToChange, actionName, descriptionName) {

    var control = $('#'+dropNameToChange);
    control.prop("disabled", false);

    $.ajax({
        //Here I need use the actionName var, but only accept a string
        url: '@Url.Action(actionName, "ThirdPartiesDef")',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { id: id },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            control.empty();
            $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                control.append(
                    $('<option/>', {
                        value: item.Id,
                        text: item[descriptionName]
                    })
                );
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error: " + error);
        }
    });
}
```

I don't know so much of ajax and if you can say me some more easy method, it's ok.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Razor code is generated server side and therefore the simple answer you can't pass Javascript as a razor overload parameter. Are you trying to generate the `Url.Action` based on what the current action name is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `JSON.stringify()` method.

`JSON.stringify()` method turns a `javascript` object to `json` text and stores it in a `string`.

You specified `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and the `server` waits to `receive` data in `json` format.

Also, you used wrong  @Url.Action : `@Url.Action(actionName, "ThirdPartiesDef")',`.

One solution is to use `.replace` function:

`'@Url.Action("myAction", "ThirdPartiesDef")'.replace('myAction', actionName)`.

**In Razor every content using a @ block is automatically HTML encoded by Razor.**

Comment: The proposed solution is bad because you hardcoded and assumed that the url structure is `/controller/action`. Also you didn't account for possible virtual directories which could lead to the application not working when deployed in IIS. That's the reason why you should always use url helpers to generate the urls in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I know this. But you already provided solution using `Html.Helpers`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a placeholder inside the `Url.Action` **server side** Razor function that will be replaced by your javascript `actionName` variable **on the client** side:

```
url: '@Url.Action("#THE-ACTION#", "ThirdPartiesDef")'.replace('#THE-ACTION#', actionName)
```

which basically will emit the following markup inside the browser **on the client**:

```
url: '/#THE-ACTION#/ThirdPartiesDef/'.replace('#THE-ACTION#', actionName)
```

which after calling the `changeDropDownList` javascript function on the client it will replace the placeholder with the `actionName` javascript variable and you will end up with the correct url to use for your AJAX call.

As a side note you should remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` parameter from your AJAX call because you are not sending any JSON at all in your `data` parameter.